# Parallizing KNN in hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce, distance, knn

While finding `K nearest neighbours`(say for set R(Test data) ans S(Train data))
we need to find `distance` between R and S.

So for that we will be loading Train data in hadoop `setup` and for each test data we will be computing distance with Testdata.
Distributed cache have a limit where it can store the data.

What will we do  if we need to find distance of a large file.

Any Other better way to do the same?

Comment: maybe you will find this paper useful: http://www.cs.utah.edu/~lifeifei/papers/mrknnj.pdf

Comment: yes one of my refered was the same one.But they are telling we need to partition the data and do the processing.But actually this is done by hadoop itself(spliting) or are they telling about partitioning the train data in setup?